# how to get distinct column value1 from a table which does not include a particular value in column value 2 when it has multiple rows with col val1?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

Probably a big Title! sorry for that.. :(

```
Table 1

id   col1    col2

1     10     one
2     11     two
3     10     three
```

Now, i would like to write a sql query to get distinct col1 from table1 which doesn't have three in col2. I need the output col1 - 11 only.

I tried like this `select distinct col1 from table1 where col2 != 'three'` but this gives the result as both 10 and 11. But for 10 it has corresponding row with three as col2 value. Kindly help me to find this.

Answer (score 1):

Use `group by` and `having`.

```
select col1 
from table1 
group by col 
having sum(case when col2='three' then 1 else 0 end)=0
```

If you are using MySQL, the `having` condition can be shortened to

```
select col1 
from table1 
group by col 
having sum(col2='three')=0
```

as conditions are treated as booleans returning 1 for true and 0 for false.

Answer (score 0):

using `not in()`

```
select distinct col1
from table1 t
where col1 not in (
  select col1
  from table1 i
  where i.col2 = 'three'
  )
```

or using `not exists()`

```
select distinct col1
from table1 t
where not exists (
  select 1
  from table1 i
  where i.col1 = t.col1
    and i.col2 = 'three'
  )
```